# remove comma inside double quotes when csv file import using classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have CSV data like this `"1233","abcxyz","1,500","Qwerty","25,000"`

How to remove commas this type of values (`"1,500"`,`"25,000"`) when importing CSV in classicASP

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV is not too big, implement a **FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile** and read it character by character, accumulating the results inside as String. Do a comparative logic to ignore all double-quotes found while reading. This will not be that easy exactly because you will be dealing with quotes, thus will require some escape technic from you.

If you have numbers in sequence, and if these numbers mark decimal points or thousands (millions etc) with commas, then you will have more troubles, cause something like your example ("1,500","25,000") after this read and write char by char would produce this: (1,500,25,000). A solution to this would be transform all commas between double quotes into `;`.

EDIT: I was thinking... maybe a readAll can do the trick too. Let's try:

```
path = Server.MapPath("\yoursite\yourfile.csv") 'this is absolute path on server (c:\ etc) - not url!
set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if fs.FileExists(path) then
     set file = fs.OpenTextFile(path, 1)
     txt = file.ReadAll
     for i = 1 to (Len(txt)-1)
          if file.Read(i) = """ then
               i = i + 1
          else
               txtaux = txtaux & file.Read(i)
          end if
     next
     file.Close()
else
     txt = " - error - "
end if
txt = txtaux
set fs = nothing
set file = nothing
```

If this runs (not sure because I am currently without a testing environment for ASP) then you will have all your CVS inside **txt** string var. Buuuuttt... we only faced the quotes matter, not commas... So you will have to make a workaround there, maybe implementing another **if** inside to detect if a comma is inside quotes, then it need to be changed to **;**, for example, something which will bring for you, as the final result, something like this: 10,000;25,000 and so on.

Comment: Edited. Not sure if 100% working but maybe pointing to the resolution of your matter. What we are doing there? Reading the CSV and accumulating its content to the txt string variable. Then we find the length of this content and begin to read it char by char until the end, skipping the reading char if it is a double quote, and building your final string without quotes. Best luck.

Comment: Had luck with that?

Comment: (know it was a post a while back but i tested and get this )
On the """ part it doesn't terminate properly throwing this error :
Unterminated string constant

Comment: Oh... hard for me to test ASP nowadays... have you tried both forms of double quotes? I mean `"` and `ˮ`? Maybe alternating them? I don't know if this can make sense with ASP. Thank you, wish you luck.

Comment: No worries at all, was just reporting back from my tests if it benefits anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is with parsing the CSV-file because of the commas you should probably use another method for reading the file in the first place. The CSV-format is more complex than values just separated with comma hence it is better to use tried and tested methods.

Check this article on how to read CSV-files using ASP (with JScript): http://mindmeat.blogspot.dk/2014/05/reading-excel-files-in-classic-asp.html

It does require ACE-drivers to be installed on the server though.